# Converter from other syntax to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My knowledge is in ASP.NET MVC C#, SQL Server 2005/2008 R2, SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio and Crystal Reports. I would like to extend my knowledge to work on existing customers CRM /CMS applications who perhaps used different syntax, such as Drupal, php, C++ or Oracle. Who need an update in uniqueness. Could someone kindly tell me where I can find resources for this kind of information? In general terms, of course. I Had a look at [MVC Framework for existing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001777/mvc-framework-for-existing-application), for reference. Also http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet, but this is for ASP.NET1 not MVC.

If there is no tool out there for ASP.NET MVC C# converter is there alternative way? I have not come from ASP.NET, Straight to MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Converting code is generally an ugly process which ends up with you having to do a lot manually. And that assumes that you are converting from/to languages that are at least being used in the same paradigm; in-line server-side scripting in PHP to in-line, server-side 'scripting' in ASP.NET, for example.

But ASP.NET MVC is a completely different paradigm for developing a web application. There really is not any useful way to 'convert' an application from in-line, scripted PHP to ASP.NET MVC; You would just end up with "views" that are just ASPX pages with in-line code, not all of which could even be converted in the first place.

Even trying to go from a different MVC web framework to ASP.NET MVC would likely be near-impossible to do completely, as different things are separated in different places.

---

So much of MVC is about architecting the application "properly" from the start. Trying to automatically convert things would really mess with that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, what you said makes sense